# Where better create Map in java?

Tags: java, dictionary

Code:

```
public class MyClass {
 private Map<Integer,String> myMap;
 ...........................


 void methodFillMap(){
    myMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  .....................
  }
}
```

Or better like:

```
public class MyClass {
 private Map<Integer,String> myMap=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
 ...........................


 void methodFillMap(){
    myMap.put(.....);

  .....................
  }

}
```

Are these 2 ways of creating map the same by efficiency and functionality?

Comment: Depends on how often you call `methodFillMap`. If only once then it doesn't matter.

Comment: yes, methodFillMap called near million times.

Comment: This usually depends on the use case. In your second method you may have to clear the map first before adding items unless you want the old items also present if not overwritten. The first method might leave a lot of weak references for the gc I think. Other than that, for the modern jvm's there are not much penalty of creating object.

Comment: Don't understand. For weak references need use WeakHashMap, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are different functionally. In your first case every time the method methodFillMap is called a new map is created and you will lose information from the old Map whereas in your second case the object will persist with the information.

Comment: But if I will add in methodFillMap: myMap.clear() it will be the same?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do with the above piece of code? Because functionally they do different things as of now!

Comment: Seems that is not good to create object each time when called method. This method can be called 1 000 000 times. But I am not sure about it.

Comment: definitely, creating objects and destroying objects are expensive operations when compared to primitive operations.

Answer (score 1):

The "time penalty" for creating an object (the map) will probably be the same in both cases. The question is - do you want the instantiation to be faster or the cal to `methodFillMap`?

Comment: Why time penalty should be the same? Does map will exist in some cache of VM?

Comment: No, but it should be instantiated in both cases.

Comment: This method can be called 1 000 000 times. Does it mean that object will be created 1 000 000 times?

Comment: Yes, if the map is instantiated inside the method.

Comment: So time penalty will be huge?

Comment: Don't know if huge, but bigger than the instantiation in the class level. I thought that this method is called once.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is the first one, that way you only create a new instance of the map when you really need it, so in case you never call the method "methodFillMap" you wont have an instance of an unused object in memory.